# Object detection only in specified region. (Defining ROI in a video frame)

Tags: python, object-detection

I want to define a region in my input frame, i,e only in this defined region my object detection should be working. The objects outside the region of interest should be ignored. I tried drawing polygons to mask unnecessary regions but the system still detects object behind it.

Roi Image:
[image: roi]

Comment: can you confirm that you are passing the right masked image to your model for object detection. because if you have already marked an image with black pixels there are no ways that the model can detect objects from that.

Comment: The image passed is without the black polygons, I used opencv in my code to draw it.

Comment: hello, did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Coder I wasn't able to solve it, I submitted the project with the whole frame analysed.